# QueryDSL - DTO projections for one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, jpa, dsl, querydsl, dto

I'm looking at using DTO projections - I have two entities with a one-to-many relationship (an instance of EntityOne is linked to multiple instances of EntityTwo) and I want to return the results as a new DTO object - what I'm trying currently is something like:

```
query.select(Projections.constructor(MyDtoObject.class,
            entityOne, list(entityTwo)))
        .from(entityOne, entityTwo)
        .where(......)
```

Where MyDtoObject looks like this:

```
public class MyDtoObject {

    private EntityOne entityOne;
    private Collection<EntityTwo> entityTwoCollection 

   // getters, setters and an all args constructor method here

}
```

However, this is bringing back a lot more MyDtoObjects than expected, and it looks like each one is only holding one entityTwo object instead of a collection.

How do I instruct queryDSL to create the MyDtoObjects result objects with multiple entityTwo entries?  Does the list(..) method even do anything in my scenario above?

Comment: I found a related answer and it solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116711/collections-in-querydsl-projections

Answer (score 3):

```
queryFactory.from(Entity)
    .transform(groupBy(Entity.something).list((    
        Projections.fields(EntityDto.class,
            list(Projections.fields(Dto.class, 
                )).as("CollectionEntity"),
    )));
```

try transform with list