# QueryDsl and Embeddables with OneToMany | Wierd Generated SQL Select by "."

Tags: sql, spring, one-to-many, querydsl, embeddable

I am expermenting querydsl with embeddable, on the following set:

```
@Entity
Class Ent1 {
   @Embedded
   Embed embed;
}

@Entity
Class Ent2 {
   @ManyToOne
   Ent1 ent1;
}

@Embeddable
Class Embed {
   @OneToMany
   List<Ent2> ent2List;
}
```

When i use following dsl query

```
query
        .select(Projections.constructor(Embed.class, QEnt1.qEnt1.ent2List))
        .from(QEnt1.qEnt1)
        .fetch();
```

Generate this sql

```
    select
        . as col0,
        ent2.ent1_id as col1
    from
        Ent1 ent1
    inner join
        Ent2 ent2 
            on ent1.id=ent2.id
```

following generated line breaks the query

> **. as col0**

Sql works fine without generated dot line, any ideas how to fix ?

Note: Im using oracle sql

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue. Did you find the solution? IF so please add it here.

Comment: @rakeeee 
thesse helped me 
-https://stackoverflow.com/a/17155721/4421254
-https://stackoverflow.com/a/68061497/4421254